# R: Interpreting results from ANOVA and TukeyHSD analyses

Tags: r, anova

I have run an ANOVA and TukeyHSD over a dataframe containing anatomical regions in column 1 (region) and gene expression values in column 2 (S1). I normally would expect the p-value from the aov summary to be expressed as **Pr(>F)**, so I'm a little fuzzy on the results I've obtained. Also, can someone help me understand the Tukey multiple comparisons of means results? I'm not totally clear on what the **diff** and **p adj** results indicate. The results shown here are an abridged version of what I'm actually working with, FYI.

```
> aov.result = aov(S1 ~ region, data=raw.data)
> summary(aov.result)
             Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
region       60  61.713 1.02856  5.9246 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals   655 113.712 0.17361                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
> TukeyHSD(aov.result)
Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = S1 ~ region, data = raw.data)

$region
                     diff           lwr          upr     p adj
AB-AA        0.4118651583 -2.864195e-01  1.110149848 0.9847745
AHA-AA      -0.0468785098 -7.608569e-01  0.667099930 1.0000000
APir-AA      0.4419135565 -2.563711e-01  1.140198246 0.9502924
B-AA         0.5379787168 -1.603060e-01  1.236263406 0.5846356
```

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your question, since the `summary.aov` output meets your expectation. `diff` is simply the difference between the two group means. `p adj` is the Tukey adjusted p value, i.e., the result of the significance test for diff (considering multiple testing). Your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with some reproducible data, one factor and one continuous variable:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
    f1=as.factor(rep(seq(1:3),4)),
    c1=abs(rnorm(12)))
s1 <- stats::aov(df1$c1 ~ df1$f1)
summary(s1)
```

This gives output similar to yours.

The P-value for your data appears correct and can be confirmed with e.g.:

```
1-stats::pf(q=5.92, df1=60, df2=655)
[1] 0
```

Now, looking at output from:

```
s2 <- stats::TukeyHSD.aov(s1)
```

i.e.

```
$`df1$f1`
           diff       lwr       upr     p adj
2-1 -0.06282377 -1.038236 0.9125887 0.9823655
3-1 -0.09820762 -1.073620 0.8772048 0.9575774
3-2 -0.03538385 -1.010796 0.9400286 0.9943641
```

The first column is the difference in the means. In my example:

```
m1 <- mean( df1$c1[df1$f1==1] )
m2 <- mean( df1$c1[df1$f1==2] )
```

Now `m2-m1` is approximately equal to `s2$"df1$f1"[1,1]`, here `-0.068..`

This 'difference of means' has a confidence interval calculated from the [studentized range (q) distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_range_distribution#The_studentized_range_.28q.29_distribution). The mechanics can be found in the source code of `stats::TukeyHSD.aov()`. See also `?ptukey`. Note also the rationale for 'correction for multiple comparisons' is  [controversial](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1112991/) in certain contexts. This sort of question might be better suited to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).